# Datetime format of a Pandas dataframe column switching randomly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I am using a dataframe which has a 'Date' column. I have used `pd.to_datetime()` to convert this column format to yyyy-mm-dd. However, this format is getting switched to some other format at intermittent dates in the dataframe (eg: yyyy-dd-mm).

```
Date 
2021-02-01 <----- this is 2nd Jan, 2021
2021-01-21 <----- this is 21st Jan, 2021
```

Further, I have alto tried using the `df['Date'].dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d')`, but this too has not helped.

I request some guidance on the following points:

1. For any Date column, is it enough to just use pd.to_datetime() and be rest assured that all dates will be in correct format?
2. Or do I need to manually state the datetime format explicitly alongwith the pd.to_[enter image description here][1]datetime() feature?

Comment: Hello @MrFuppes, this works perfectly !. Thank you so much !. My program's error has got resolved. Really appreciate your help !

Comment: Just one small question: From model stability perspective, in case I have 3 different dataframes', and each have a Date column in them, is it a best practice to use the "dayFirst=True" property? . Is it advisable to use it always from a model stability perspective?

Comment: This depends on your input. If you get that from a region of the world where it is common to put the day first in a date, then you can set it to True in general. But be aware there are regions where this is not the case, e.g. the US. If you want to be 100% sure and receive an error for invalid dates, set a specific format, e.g. `'%d-%m-%Y'` for inputs like `"02-01-2021"` (Jan 2nd, 2021).

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from how pandas parses dates.
When receiving `2021-02-01` it does not know if it is Feb 1st or Jan 2nd, so it applies its default decision rules: when the date starts with the year, the next field is the month, so resulting in Feb 1st.
This is not the case when parsing `2021-01-21`, there is only one possible date, Jan 21st.

Take a look at [to_datetime documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), and its parameters `day_first` or `format`, to force a given format when there are different possible parsings

Comment: Thank you @Pantoofle. Appreciate your response. I will refer to the documentation further. I will get back in case of any queries

Comment: my issue got resolve using dayFirst property. thank you

Comment: Nice ! You can mark the answer as valid, so that next users can more easily see that this answer worked for you